# Pandas filter rows with lists

Tags: pandas

I have a column in a pandas dataframe that is a string, something like:

```
df['hello'].iloc[0] = '['hi','how','are','you']'
```

And I want to keep only the rows that have the word 'you', but after 'how'.
Something like this condition:

`'you' in ['hi','how','are','you'].split('how')[1]` > keep the row

I tried this:

```
filtered = df[df['hello'].map(ast.literal_eval).apply(lambda x: 'you' in x)]
```

but it only filters rows with you, not after 'how'.
How can I add this condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check it with regex pattern in `.str.contains`, matching strings where `'how'` is followed by any characters and then followed by `'you'`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'hello': [
    "['hi','how','are','you']",
    "['you','are','how']",
]})

filtered = df.loc[df['hello'].str.contains("'how'.*'you'")]
filtered
```

Output:

```
                      hello
0  ['hi','how','are','you']
```

Comment: I want the result to df without the last row, not a new column

Comment: @crazybanana101 Sure, please see the updated anwer